# Xamarin Forms XAML Pass Static Value To Simple Data Type

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is the second time something like this has come up for me. Wondering if anyone knows if this is possible in Xamarin Forms' XAML. Something like:

```
<Color x:Key="Green">{x:Static common:Constants.LightBackgroundColor}</Color>
```

Obviously the above will not compile. I tried using `<Color Accent="">` but it did not like that. I get the following using the code above:

> Cannot convert "{x:Static common:Constants.LightBackgroundColor}" into
>   Xamarin.Forms.Color" System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.    at
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, ParamsArray args)    at
>   System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format,
>   ParamsArray args)    at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.LazyFormattedBuildEventArgs.FormatString(CultureInfo
>   culture, String unformatted, Object[]
>   args) VirtualAdvisor  C:\Users...

I also tried doing something with `x:Arguments` but then I run into the same issue... if only one of these things had a `Value` property I could specify or something....

Also, I realize that I could just put the real hex `string` or `Color` value in but because of how the different projects are being referenced I need to keep the `Color` value outside of my Xamarin Forms shared project but would still like to access the Color values from `App.xaml`, maybe I need to just give up on `App.xaml` at this point, at least for these `Color` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting issue, reproduced it successfully.
When you put `x:Static ...` inside your App.xaml resource dictionary you get:

```
Error MSB4018: The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
This is an unhandled exception from a task -- PLEASE OPEN A BUG AGAINST THE TASK OWNER.
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.


Server stack trace: 
  at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args) [0x000e9] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs:1371 
  at System.String.FormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args) [0x00011] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/string.cs:2978 
  at System.String.Format (System.String format, System.Object[] args) [0x00021] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/string.cs:2943 
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.FormatString (System.String unformatted, System.Object[] args) [0x00021] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Utilities/Microsoft.Build.Utilities/TaskLoggingHelper.cs:93 
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.LogError (System.String subcategory, System.String errorCode, System.String helpKeyword, System.String file, System.Int32 lineNumber, System.Int32 columnNumber, System.Int32 endLineNumber, System.Int32 endColumnNumber, System.String message, System.Object[] messageArgs) [0x00026] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Utilities/Microsoft.Build.Utilities/TaskLoggingHelper.cs:134 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper:LogError (string,string,string,string,int,int,int,int,string,object[])
  at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.LogError (System.String subcategory, System.String errorCode, System.String helpKeyword, System.String file, System.Int32 lineNumber, System.Int32 columnNumber, System.Int32 endLineNumber, System.Int32 endColumnNumber, System.String message, System.Object[] messageArgs) [0x00024] in <8cb029844f1042e6a4a06f623985b8f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.LogException (System.String subcategory, System.String errorCode, System.String helpKeyword, System.String file, System.Exception e) [0x0004e] in <8cb029844f1042e6a4a06f623985b8f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] thrownExceptions) [0x00583] in <8cb029844f1042e6a4a06f623985b8f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute () [0x00007] in <8cb029844f1042e6a4a06f623985b8f8>:0 
  at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask:Execute (object,byte[]&,byte[]&)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask:Execute ()
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x0002a] in <6f3322fc0bd04a64a6c8db7c8cfce40d>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext () [0x002bf] in <6f3322fc0bd04a64a6c8db7c8cfce40d>:0  (MSB4018) (staticx)
```

However if you include [x:Static](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml_markup_extensions/#The_xStatic_Markup_Extension) on a ContentPage xaml for example it works without any problem.

In this case I would define static properties in a separate class, (like you have already) and access them directly, without defining them in App.Xaml

P.S.:
To catch XAML errors at compilation time you have to add one line to `AssemblyInfo.cs` :

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

**Edit:**
For me the `x:Static` tag in app xaml breaking the compilation, however I found a workaround. If you add your color programmatically it works. Example:

Defenetion of static value:

```
public class Constants
{
    public static string StaticColor = "#456654";
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    if (Current.Resources == null)
    {
        Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
    }

    Current.Resources.Add("staticValue" ,Color.FromHex(Constants.StaticColor));

    MainPage = new TestPage();
}
```

Usage:

```
<Label TextColor="{x:StaticResource staticValue}" Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" />
```

Comment: Actually, I can usually use `x:Static` in general in `App.xaml`, my problem is how to use it to specify a simple data type's value like `Color`. I added the exception I get using the code in my question.